# How can I implement multiple resolves in a State, when one is a function that must return promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a function that returns one or more promises as it loads resources, in this case, jsRequires-defined modules that are passed to the function. The function is provided as the value of 'resolve:' and therefore it is just like a factory function and the return value(s) will be injected to the main controller of the application.
It works perfectly like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
url: "/app",
templateUrl: "assets/views/apphome.html",
resolve: loadSequence('moment', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'toaster')
})
//.state(' ...
//etc.

function loadSequence(){
//...
return promise;
//... etc.
}
```

When I want to add more resolves, because you obviously cannot have multiple "resolve:', I must do it like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
url: "/app",
templateUrl: "assets/views/apphome.html",
resolve: {
    key1:   value,
    key2:   loadSequence('moment', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'toaster')
}
})
//.state(' ...
//etc.
```

My loadSequence function cannot be added here as a value, because then my promises won't be injected and be available for the State. If I do that I will get this error:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

My question is not that much about the error.
How can I add my loadSequence function in a fashion that it continues to work as indicated first above?

Comment: if I understand your problem, you have to wrap it in a function like:
key2: function() { return loadSequence('moment', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'toaster') }

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
$stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    templateUrl: "assets/views/apphome.html",
    resolve: {
        key1:   value,
        key2:   function(){return loadSequence('moment', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'toaster');}
    }
})
```

Comment: With "resolve: loadSequence( ...", the resulting promises are injected into $rootScope. The variables defined by the modules are directly accessible. When using multiple resolves, angular-ui-router will try inject the promises into key2, which is not possible. That's the challange.